# Add 2d array to make 3d in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a requirement to read image files( 28*28) from a folder and stack them together to make a single array for analysis.

I have the following code:

```
for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, fname))
    imarray = np.array(im)
    final = np.stack((final,imarray ), axis = 0)
```

am getting the following error:
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape

imarray is (28,28) and i have 60K images in that folder so i want to make a array of size (60000,28,28)

Thanks for the help
NK

Comment: Add these images to a list (in loop) and call vstack with that list as input (not in loop). That's especially important for performance. Or if you know a-priori how many imgs are coming incl. their shape: build an empty 3d-array and add these to this array (better approach).

Comment: i tried this for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, fname))
    imarray = np.array(im)
    fin = np.empty((60000,28,28))
    fin = np.vstack((fin,imarray )) and getting the error "all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions"

Comment: I described two different approaches, don't mix them. Also: that's impossible to read. Well... hpaulj's answer is covering the first approach. If his solution is not working, your assumption on the shape (28,28) is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a list of all components and stack them once:

```
alist = []
for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, fname))
    imarray = np.array(im)
    alist.append(imarray)
final = np.stack(alist)   # axis=0 is the default
```

This will join them on a new initial axis.

Comment: thanks that worked!! can it be done without the list as well ( just asking)

Comment: Yes, with my second approach. It also saves ~50% of memory. ```arr=np.empty((60000, 28, 28))``` outside the loop, then ```arr[i] = img``` for every i inside.

Comment: Yes, but list append is more efficient that array concatenate.  Insertion in a preallocated array tends to be as fast.

Comment: thanks Sascha , it worked too. sorry i misunderstood earlier. last question i have is if i don't know the count of images then the 2 approach is the only option 

also if if size of images are not same for all images say one is 28*28 , 64*64 etc will the 2nd approach still works?

Comment: Incomplete a-priori info about n-imgs: list-approach only or wasting cells (or other effects). None of these approaches will work for different shapes.